# Is it possible to upgrade Artifactory in some sort of blue/green solution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, artifactory

We have a very critical Artifactory instance hosted on AWS. It uses ECS (one container for Artifactory), EFS, S3 and RDS.

We want to improve our upgrade process. Now we deploy an upgraded Artifactory Docker image and pray that everything goes well. We're currently exploring if it's possible to have 2 Artifactory instances (2 containers) running at the same time, like a [blue green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue%E2%80%93green_deployment) solution.

We were thinking about replicating EFS too, but keep the same RDS and s3 storage. Is this possible? Or will we end up with join.key troubles and should we also have 2 separate RDS instances? I can't find much about it in the docs.

We want to run those 2 Artifactory versions side by side and do some testing. In the end we can switch URLs to the new container.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways you can proceed here. It is very important we don't confuse them.

1. You can set up Artifactory to make use of **High availability** mode
   (Ha for short). This requires 2 enterprise licenses, one for each
   node. The instructions can be found
   [here](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/artifactory-ha-installation)
   and more general information
   [here](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-installation-setup-documentation/high-availability).
   The quick instructions are:

   1. Set up a separate container with its own local storage.
   2. Install Artifactory.
   3. Ensure it has the same master.key.
   4. Set haEnabled: true in the system.yaml.
   5. Connect to the same database and s3 bucket.
   6. Set up Load balancer
2. Alternatively, you can set up a fully independent Artifactory, with its own database (it can share the s3 bucket). Do not connect it as an HA node. You can then set up [repository replication](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/repository-replication) to keep these separate deployments in sync.

I would suggest reaching out to Jfrog support if you need more information and help with this.